# Calendar DatePicker in the future

Tags: java, datetime, selenium-webdriver

I want to be able to make javascript to automatically pick 2 days from today date, dont no how to execute it. "ValueFrom" is currently picking LocalDate automatically.

Code to be change: "ValueTo"

```java
public CorporateMessagesPage selectDateAndPlaceOrder() 
{
    String valueFrom = "arguments[0].value = '" + DateTime.now().toString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'";


    String valueTo = (valueFrom +2);

    JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
    System.out.print(String.valueOf(LocalDate.now()));

    javascriptExecutor.executeScript(valueFrom, validFromDate);

    javascriptExecutor.executeScript(valueTo, validToDate);

    return PageFactory.initElements(webDriver, CorporateMessagesPage.class);
}
```

I want 'ValueTo' to be equal to 'ValueFrom' + 2 days.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

You can do all this in Java with its industry-leading *java.time* classes. No need for JavaScript.

```
LocalDate                          // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone or offset-from-UTC.
.now()                             // Capture the date as seen in the wall-clock time in the JVM’s current default time zone. Better to specify the desired/expected time zone explicitly.
.plusDays( 2 )                     // Date math, adding days to move forward in time.
.format(                           // Generate text to represent the value of this date.
    DateTimeFormatter              // Specify format.
    .ofLocalizedDate(              // Automatically localize according to the human language and cultural norms of a specific `Locale`. 
        FormatStyle.SHORT          // How long or abbreviated to present this value.
    )                              // Returns a `DateTimeFormatter` object.
    .withLocale( Locale.UK )       // Returns another `DateTimeFormatter` object, per Immutable Objects pattern.
)                                  // Returns a `String`.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/HKqHpv).

> 03/08/2019

## *java.time*

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

### Date math

Use the `plus…` & `minus…` methods found on `LocalDate` to move ahead or behind in time.

```
LocalDate dayAfterNext = LocalDate.now( z ).plusDays( 2 ) ;
```

Or use `Period` class.

```
Period twoDays = Period.ofDays( 2 ) ;
LocalDate later = LocalDate.now( z ).plus( twoDays ) ;
```

### Generating text

Use `DateTimeFormatter` to generate text representing the value of the `LocalDate` object. You can either automatically localize or specify a custom formatting pattern. Both have been covered many times already on Stack Overflow, so search to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java calendar to get your desired time

```
        SimpleDateFormat obj_dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();

        //get valueFrom
        String valueFrom = obj_dateFormat.format(new Date(calender.getTimeInMillis()));

         //Add 2 days in current time
        calender.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);

        //get valueTo
        String valueTo = obj_dateFormat.format(new Date(calender.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this scripts doesn't working, it does not input todays date. The code I sent works fine for the ValueFrom string but i just need to do adjust the code for ValueTo to pick 2 days after @Moieen Abbas

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310.

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating how overly complicated it is when using the old and outdated datetime classes. This is *not* the approach one would want to use.